# rails updating a user's record by their email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have an app with an account model and an account manager (user).

I would like the account manager to be able to add other users to the account by typing in their email.

The account id of the account manager should be added to the new user's record.

My model looks like

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many users
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to account
  ...
end
```

In the console it's fairly simple.

```
u = User.find(2) 
u.update_attributes(account_id: 1)
```

But I'm not sure how to do this on the site.

I have the below partial which renders fine but when I put an email in the box nothing happens.

I get the message, user not added.

```
<h4>Add User</h4>
<div class = "row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for(:add_user, url: add_users_path) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field @account = Account.find(params[:id]) %>
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class:'form-control' %>
      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't necessarily want/need to route to another page for example "url: add_users_path" but without that line the code breaks and won't render.

I added this to user.rb

```
def add_user_to_account
  update_attribute(:account_id)
end
```

I also created this controller

```
class AddUsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :get_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if @user
        @user.add_user_to_account
        flash[:info] =  "Added User to Account"
        redirect_to accounts_url
    else 
        flash[:danger] = "User NOT Added"
        redirect_to accounts_url
    end 
  end

  def update
    if params[:user][:account_id].empty?
      @user.errors.add(:account_id, "can't be empty")
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Account Updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end  


  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:account_id, :user_id)
    end

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end
end
```

Am I on the right track?  Is there a better way to do this?

UPDATE: Added schema

```
create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "account_manager_id"
    t.integer  "subscription_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
    t.string   "password_digest",   null: false
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.string   "email",             null: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated"
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.boolean  "access_granted"
    t.boolean  "requested_access"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.integer  "account_id"
  end
```

Comment: would it be possible that you can share some of the schema for the models in question. 

Thanks

Comment: @MZaragoza I updated with the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you had the params wrong.

you are using `params[:email]` instead of `params[:add_user][:email]` to find the user by email

in you controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def add_users
     user = User.find_by(email: params[:add_user][:email])
     if user
       user.add_user_to_account
       ...
     else
       ...
     end
  end 
end
```

Comment: when i do that I get "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"